# PHP webshell pass the value using wget or URL

Tags: php, eval, burp

I have PHP-shall and I want to pass a value for the eval function. I want to pass the value to "mypass", is it possible to do so with URL or command line?

```
<!--?php eval($_POST[mypass]);?-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain to you how dangerous this is. To have eval in it's own can be a massive hazard to the system, forget having user input being processed by eval. You could run things that would control the entire system. That being said, your php is opening and closing wrong

`<?php`  Not `<!--?php`

Next your var isnt being accessed as expected, you forgot the dollar sign:
`$_POST[$mypass]` unless the parameter is "mypass" which it should be `$_POST["mypass"]`

Lastly, you'll find that in a post, you can't use your browser. Use postman or change `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: Thanks, I am not coding but creating a training for wrong coding